# CSS Reverse animation not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to reverse an animation but the class is being added but the animation does not occur. Is there something wrong with my code? Or am i missing an important animation principle?

As of now, there are animation classes that take care of the forward and reverse animation, but I need to be able to reverse the animations instead of creating a new animation to bring the elements back to the original state.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="posrel">
    <h1 class="white heading-abs">Heading</h1>
    <div class="redbg round divabs"></div>
    <button role="button" class="clickButton white customfont">Click</button>
    <button role="button" class="originalState white customfont">Original State</button>
<div>
```

CSS:

body
    {
        background: black;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
    }

```
.posrel
{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.white
{
    color: white;
}

.heading-abs
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 5%;
}

.round
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
}

.clickButton
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
}

.redbg
{
    background-color: red;
}

.divabs
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scalebubbleani
{
    -webkit-animation: scalebubbleanim 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scalebubbleanim
{
    0%
    {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }

    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    }
}

*:focus
{
    outline: none;
}

.moveheadingani
{
    -webkit-animation: moveheadinganim 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveheadinganim
{
    0%
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 30%;
    }

    100%
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 110%;
        top: 25%;
    }
}

.customfont
{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
}

.originalState
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.66);
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 0%;
}

.moveheadingbackani
{
    -webkit-animation: moveheadingbackanim 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveheadingbackanim
{
    0%
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 110%;
        top: 25%;
    }

    100%
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 30%;  
    }
}

.scalebubbleoriginalani
{
    -webkit-animation: scalebubbleoriginalanim 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scalebubbleoriginalanim
{
    0%
    {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    }

    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clickButton').click(function(){
        $('.round').addClass('scalebubbleani');
        $('.heading-abs').addClass('moveheadingani');
        $('.round').removeClass('scalebubbleoriginalani');
        $('.heading-abs').removeClass('moveheadingbackani');
    });

    $('.originalState').click(function(){
        $('.heading-abs').addClass('moveheadingbackani');
        $('.round').addClass('scalebubbleoriginalani');
        $('.round').removeClass('scalebubbleani');
        $('.heading-abs').removeClass('moveheadingani');
    });
});
```

Having to reverse an animation would make my CSS code simpler and concise.

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qyya3521/

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use with  [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clickButton').click(function(){
  $('.round').addClass('round-pressed');
        $('.heading-abs').addClass('heading-abs-pressed');
 });

 $('.originalState').click(function(){
  $('.round').removeClass('round-pressed');
  $('.heading-abs').removeClass('heading-abs-pressed');
 });
});
```

```css
body
{
 background: black;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
}
.posrel
{
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}
.white
{
 color: white;
}
.heading-abs
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
 top: 5%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.heading-abs-pressed {
 left: 110%;
 top: 25%;
}
.round
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.round-pressed{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    transform: scale(0.2);
}
.clickButton
{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: blue;
 border: none;
}
.redbg
{
 background-color: red;
}
.divabs
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;    
}
.customfont
{
 font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
}
.originalState
{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.66);
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15%;
 left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posrel">
 <h1 class="white heading-abs">Heading</h1>
 <div class="redbg round divabs"></div>
 <button role="button" class="clickButton white customfont">Click</button>
 <button role="button" class="originalState white customfont">Original State</button>
<div>
```

To make it cross browser you also should use `transform` and `transition` together with `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transition`.